# Не могу настроить редирект в .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

Надо настроить редирект с страниц старого сайта на новый, но не оч.получается.

Страница старого сайта: `http://site.com/rout.php?from=city1&to=city2`

Страница нового сайта: `**https**://newsite.com/ru/routs/city1-city2.html`

Пытался вот так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} from=(.*) [NC]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} to=(.*) [NC]

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ru/routs/%1-%2\.html [R=301,L]
```

Помогите написать рабочий вариант.

Comment: что сделать то хотите, чтобы по новому урл выполнялся старый скрипт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
RewriteEngine On
#выделяем из get переменных оба города за раз
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bfrom=([^&]+).*&to=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ru/routs/%1-%2\.html? [R=301,L]
# случай, когда переменные перепутаны местами
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \bto=([^&]+).*&from=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ru/routs/%2-%1\.html? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо